# Can I keep data of different file formats in same hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am receiving data of formats like csv, xml, json and I want to keep all the files in same hive table.Is it achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this through a combination of different external tables.

Because different SerDes with different specifications for how to read columns in the different files will be needed, you will need to create one external table per type of file (and table). The data from each of these external tables can then be combined into a view with UNION, as suggested by Ramesh. The view can could then be used for reading from these, and you could e.g. insert the data into a managed table.

Answer (score 1):

Hive expects all the files for one table to use the same delimiter, same compression applied etc. So, you cannot use a Hive table on top of files with multiple formats.

The solution you may want to use is

- Create a separate table (json/xml/csv) for each of the file formats
- Create a view for the UNION of the 3 tables created above.

This way the consumer of the data has to query only one view/object, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: WRONG. You can create a partitioned table `stored as Parquet`, then `alter table` to change the default to CSV (without cascading the alteration to existing partitions), then create new partitions. But I admit it's a very, very dirty hack.

Comment: Also, the compression options are managed dynamically -- if the same folder contains files with `.csv` and files with `.csv.gz` then each type will be read with the appropriate compression codec.